# Monitor keywords from my Twitter contacts

Tags: twitter

I know it is possible to subscribe to keywords searches by saving them within Twitter's app as a [saved search](https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/110-search/articles/96646-how-to-save-searches). There doesn't seem to be a way to get notified by email of these searches nor scope the searches to my followers or followees, e.g. An RSS feed or daily email

If this isn't possible, us there any service that would alert me when a follower or followee mentions a keyword? I realise there are services like [monitter](http://monitter.com/) and [twinitor](http://www.twinitor.com/) which monitor keywords, but none on the basis of an individual account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not affiliated with, but recommend [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) which lets you set monitors for keywords and alert you in a number of ways—email is one of them.

I think there's another site which aggregates use of a keyword into a list/email - although I believe that only works for keyword history (not real-time alerting).

If you want the keyword notification specific to your 'following and followers' a further, more in-depth look would be required—I don't know if IFTTT allows for more control over keyword specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I created a service called https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com built specifically for this purpose, to search Twitter not only based on your keywords but also other criteria like number of followers and location.

You can then set up email alerts to receive these tweets on whatever schedule you choose.

Comment: Okay, so that's three answers in a relatively short amount of time, all touting your project. Of your three other answers, two are touting another of your projects. I think you may be here for the wrong reason.

Comment: Sorry but this product is very relevant to all those answers.